# An adjective for ‘in the process of forming’

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an adjective meaning ‘in the process of forming/shaping/being formed/being created’.

> The ———— institutions have to deal with such difficulties.

I want an adjective to mean that the institution ‘is still in the process of being created.’

Comment: You don't get a single adjective for that. You hafta use an adjective phrase: _Institutions in the process of formation_

Comment: [grammar: No the, just an adjective, and a plural noun]

Comment: @Lambie "**The** budding institutions" is  all right. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20budding%20institutions%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @LPH I get tired of repeating the same things. If he is making a general statement about institutions, there would most likely not be a need for the. It is **not a grammar mistake**; it would be a mistake in situ for his probable context. And by the way, these things cannot be googled. You just have to have internalized it. "Dogs can bark frequently. "**The** large dogs in my neck of the woods often do." You can't do that in French: you always need a determiner.  Les chiens and Les chiens.

Comment: @Lambie You have to come to grips with the fact: there is a whole page of such instances, where the determination is general, and  almost all are from recent origin. Maybe you want to force people to omit the article, but there is for the time being no error either in using or not using the article. Both options are correct.

Comment: @Lambie "The dogs can bark frequently" is wrong. It is different. You should write a paper on a theory of uniformization of the use of articles!

Comment: @LPH what if "the dogs" were some previously-specified group of dogs? And by the way many of your examples are not actually general, they are specified later in the sentence, usually with "of" directly afterwards.

Comment: @Lambie I understand perfectly well what you are saying and you ignore totally what *I* am saying.

Comment: @Esther Sorry I couldn't answer sooner (notification got lost somehow). You are right, not actually many but most of the examples are of the type comprising a specification by means of a prepositional phrase or  postpositive adjectival phrase. I overlooked that. So, there is not much in that argument. Nevertheless, considering the head-word by itself, the term "the institutions" is found often (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20institutions%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en). this corresponds to what CoGEL calls the larger situation: _the airlines, the schools, the institutions, etc._. (1/3)

Comment: @Esther This larger situation may be world-wide or be shared by all the inhabitants in a given country. The term "budding institutions" is no different: just as there is in any country its set of institutions, there is also its set of budding institutions. This means that both practices are used for the same generic purpose. It is even possible to oppose the partitive meaning obtained through the use of the zero article: "The institutions are an indomitable force in this country, but budding institutions can be found which differ much in that respect as they do not depend as much  (2/3)

Comment: @Esther on central power.". Concerning "The dogs …" I was thinking only about the generic case. For instance, you can say "The Germans are good musicians." but you can't say "_The_ cows are four-legged animals"; it has to be "Cows are …". (3/3)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest **nascent**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nascent) has

> **nascent**
> <sub>adjective</sub>
>
> **1** (especially of a process or organization) just coming into existence and beginning to display signs of future potential.
> *Indian book retailing is also a relatively nascent industry.*

The requested sentence can be

> [The] nascent institutions have to deal with such difficulties.

I am unsure of the context, and whether an article is needed.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers already given are correct, but with ***institutions*** I would go with ***emerging*** which means

> growing and developing, esp. in business investment:
>
> - US government and business must become partners in breaking into these emerging markets. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/emerging))

***Emerging institutions*** is much more common, as you can see from this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=budding%20institutions%2Cemerging%20institutions%2C%20inchoate%20institutions&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbudding%20institutions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemerging%20institutions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinchoate%20institutions%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbudding%20institutions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemerging%20institutions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinchoate%20institutions%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[YourDictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/emerging) says

> Things that are emerging are just being born — or they're reaching an adult state. *The important thing is they're growing and developing*. Emerging means something close to *sprouting* — when you think of this word, think "**growing**."

Comment: Oh look, institutions with an s. Just as I said. :)

Comment: Unless the OP corrects the verb of the sentence to _has_, I don't see how the subject could be singular.

Comment: My point is that in English, general statements do not take a determiner when the noun is countable. And you have made it and have not put in a pesky the.

Comment: I do agree, "the" is not necessary here, _UNLESS_ you oppose this category with another class. Like say, _**The** emerging institutions are more numerous than **the** established ones in this country._

Comment: Yes, of course. In that way, the items are made specific.

Answer (score 1):

**inchoate**

**Merriam Webster:**

Synonyms & Antonyms of inchoate
*beginning to come into existence*
inchoate feelings of affection for a man whom she had, up till now, thought of as only a friend
Synonyms for inchoate

budding, inceptive, incipient, nascent

Inchoate institutions have to deal with similar difficulties [or: such as these].

[NB: EQ-NAIC]

Answer (score -1):

*budding*

> (OALD) ***budding*** adjective  /ˈbʌdɪŋ/ [only before noun]
> ​beginning to develop or become successful
> • a budding artist/writer

- The budding institutions have to deal with such difficulties.

*emerging*

> (OALD) ***emerging*** adjective /ɪˈmɜːdʒɪŋ/  /ɪˈmɜːrdʒɪŋ/ [only before noun]
> ​starting to exist, grow or become  known
> • the emerging markets of South Asia
> • emerging economies/democracies
> • an emerging artist/talent
> • newly emerging areas of science
> • He also analyses the industry to identify emerging technologies.